# Trying to call external HTTP Post request through camel inside Tomcat

Tags: java, http, tomcat, routes, apache-camel

I am new to Apache Camel and was able to set up an initial hello servlet successfully. I am using Apache Camel inside Tomcat container.

Below is my camel-config.xml

```
  <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

<route id="helloRoute">
  <!-- incoming requests from the servlet is routed -->
  <from uri="servlet:hello"/>
  <choice>
    <when>
      <!-- is there a header with the key name? -->
      <header>name</header>
      <!-- yes so return back a message to the user -->
      <transform>
        <simple>Hi I am ${sysenv.HOSTNAME}. Hello ${header.name} how are you today?</simple>
      </transform>
    </when>
    <otherwise>
      <!-- if no name parameter then output a syntax to the user -->
      <transform>
        <constant>Add a name parameter to uri, eg ?name=foo</constant>
      </transform>
    </otherwise>
  </choice>
</route>
<route id="svRoute">
    <from uri="servlet:camel/sxx-search"/>
    <to uri="https4://sxx.abc.com/sxx/sxx.php"/>
</route>
</camelContext>
```

and here is code from my web.xml

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>CamelServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.camel.component.servlet.CamelHttpTransportServlet</servlet-class>
      </servlet>

      <!-- Camel servlet mapping -->
      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CamelServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/camel/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

When I hit 
    http://localhost:port/camel/hello?name=Mr
I get the desired response.

Currently, in my below code, I am hitting an external HTTP URL with XML as a post request and in response receives the XML(String)

```
String xml="<some input to the httppost>"
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("camel/sxx-search"); //tryin to map this in route defined in config.xml above
 SSLContext sslctx= SSLContexts.createSystemDefault();

    SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
            sslctx,
            new String[] { "TLSv1", "TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2" },
            null,
            SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getDefaultHostnameVerifier());

    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf)
            .addInterceptorFirst(new RequestAcceptEncoding())   // adds gzip encoding header
            .build();

    CloseableHttpResponse response = null;
    List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("xml", xml)); // URLEncoding taken care of in the next line

    try {
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps));
        response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
        result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8"); } catch(Exception e) {...}
```

Now, I want to execute this httpPost request through camel route. Can anyone help me to guide me in the right direction? Like how can I change the above http code to go through Camel routes.

I have tried using

```
camel/sxx-search
```

in HttpPost as written above. So that it can route through camel to

```
"https4://sxx.abc.com/sxx/sxx.php"
```

and after hitting

```
http://localhost:8080/camel/sxx-search
```

the application throws 404 Error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the http method to be a POST?

The [camel docs](http://camel.apache.org/http4.html) have examples of how to set it in the message header. e.g.

```
  <route>
    <from uri="direct:start"/>
    <setHeader headerName="CamelHttpMethod">
        <constant>POST</constant>
    </setHeader>
    <to uri="http4://www.google.com"/>
    <to uri="mock:results"/>
  </route>
```

I assume you'll also need to set the data to be POSTed in he message body.

Comment: I am already using HttpPost API, I want to post to Apache Camel uri using HttpPost API. Is that possible ?